# Bootstrap Date Picker : Failed to appendChild on Node

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Getting above error, when I trying to use eonasdan-datetimepicker in my page.Included files are in the following order,

```
jquery.js
moment.js
transition.js
collapse.js
bootstrap-min.js
bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
```

In Script,

```
$('#monthpicker').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: "years",
    format: 'MM/YYYY' 
 });
```

But,Not getting date selection drop down.
**Note:** Included bootstrap-datetimepicker.css,bootstrap.min,css

Comment: Did you include Bootstrap (JS/CSS)?

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap 3 css @makshh

Comment: You have to load JS file from Bootstrap too (for dropdown)

Comment: @makshh Yes Included,but no use

Comment: Check if your jQuery is above or equal to version 1.9.1 (requirement for datempicker)

Comment: @makshh I didnt check the jquery version. Now lot of other jquery function are getting problem. I can fix those. Thanks